# Post in Twitter using C# application

Tags: c#, twitter

I can able to post the tweet through my application using C# with twitterizer API,and the new post is posted in my twiiter site like this

"New Post: This Post for twitter test 
about 18 hours ago from Twitterizer"

in this in the bottom it is showing as "twitterizer" but i don't want to show the tool name  to my users..is there any way to hide that "twitterizer" or is it possible to rename as my application name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply your own source to the Twitterizer library using the following constructor:

```
public Twitter(string UserName, string Password, string Source)
```

Comment: i changed as public twitter(username, password, myname);
it is now changed as web instead of twitterzer, is that i can specifically give my name in the place of web..