# Post "Hello World" to twitter from .NET application

Tags: c#, twitter

My client would like me to use .NET to post to Twitter, and suggests that I use C#.

Q: How do I post "Hello World" to twitter using C#?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692602/post-in-twitter-using-c-application) mentions a library called twitterizer.  Isn't there a native way to do it without using a 3rd party library?  (Maybe not since authentication is one of the requirements).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use this implemented wrapper for the Twitter API:

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

```
    var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()   
    .AuthenticateAs("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")   
    .Statuses().Update("Hello World!")   
    .AsJson();   

    var response = twitter.Request();
```

From: http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2009/04/23/howto-tweet-with-c/

[There is even a DotNetRocks interview with the developers.](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=456)

Comment: tweetsharp is dead

Answer (score 6):

I created a video tutorial showing exactly how to setup the application inside twitter, install an API Library using nuget, accept an access token from a user and post on that user's behalf:

Video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGEA1sgMMqU

Tutorial: http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Grant-Access-And-Tweet-As-Twitter-User-ASPNet

In case you don't want to leave this page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Twitterizer;

namespace PostFansTwitter
{
    public partial class twconnect : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var oauth_consumer_key = "gjxG99ZA5jmJoB3FeXWJZA";
            var oauth_consumer_secret = "rsAAtEhVRrXUTNcwEecXqPyDHaOR4KjOuMkpb8g";

            if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
            {
                OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                    oauth_consumer_key,
                    oauth_consumer_secret,
                    Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

                Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
                    reqToken.Token));
            }
            else
            {
                string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
                string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();

                var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
                    oauth_consumer_key,
                    oauth_consumer_secret,
                    requestToken,
                    pin);

                OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
                {
                    AccessToken = tokens.Token,
                    AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
                    ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
                    ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
                };

                TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
                    accesstoken,
                    "Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

                if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
                {
                    Response.Write("we did it!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("it's all bad.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it without any third-party library. See my [IronPython sample](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Tweet#Using_the_Framework_Only) posted on the [IronPython Cookbook](http://www.ironpython.info/) site that shows you exactly how. Even if you don't program in IronPython, the main part of the code that should get you started is repeated below and easy to port to C#:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False 
wc = WebClient(Credentials = NetworkCredential(username, password))
wc.Headers.Add('X-Twitter-Client', 'Pweeter')
form = NameValueCollection()
form.Add('status', status)
wc.UploadValues('http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml', form)
```

Basically, this does an HTTP POST to http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml with a single HTML FORM field called `status` and which contains the status update text for the account identified by `username` (and `password`).

Comment: That works fine today, but will stop working when Twitter turns off basic auth next month.

Comment: +1 for actually comprehending the question (doing it with an API).

Answer (score 4):

The best example I have found after searching all night is at the following link:

[Simplest C# code to post a tweet using OAuth](https://blog.dantup.com/2016/07/simplest-csharp-code-to-post-a-tweet-using-oauth/)

First you need to go to [developer.twitter.com](https://developer.twitter.com) and create a Twitter app, complete with API Keys and Access tokens (under Details > Keys and tokens).

The class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple class for sending tweets to Twitter using Single-user OAuth.
/// https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user
/// 
/// Get your access keys by creating an app at apps.twitter.com then visiting the
/// "Keys and Access Tokens" section for your app. They can be found under the
/// "Your Access Token" heading.
/// </summary>
class TwitterApi
{
    const string TwitterApiBaseUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
    readonly string consumerKey, consumerKeySecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret;
    readonly HMACSHA1 sigHasher;
    readonly DateTime epochUtc = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an object for sending tweets to Twitter using Single-user OAuth.
    /// 
    /// Get your access keys by creating an app at apps.twitter.com then visiting the
    /// "Keys and Access Tokens" section for your app. They can be found under the
    /// "Your Access Token" heading.
    /// </summary>
    public TwitterApi(string consumerKey, string consumerKeySecret, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret)
    {
        this.consumerKey = consumerKey;
        this.consumerKeySecret = consumerKeySecret;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.accessTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret;

        sigHasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerKeySecret, accessTokenSecret)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a tweet with the supplied text and returns the response from the Twitter API.
    /// </summary>
    public Task<string> Tweet(string text)
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "status", text },
            { "trim_user", "1" }
        };

        return SendRequest("statuses/update.json", data);
    }

    Task<string> SendRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var fullUrl = TwitterApiBaseUrl + url;

        // Timestamps are in seconds since 1/1/1970.
        var timestamp = (int)((DateTime.UtcNow - epochUtc).TotalSeconds);

        // Add all the OAuth headers we'll need to use when constructing the hash.
        data.Add("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey);
        data.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
        data.Add("oauth_timestamp", timestamp.ToString());
        data.Add("oauth_nonce", "a"); // Required, but Twitter doesn't appear to use it, so "a" will do.
        data.Add("oauth_token", accessToken);
        data.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");

        // Generate the OAuth signature and add it to our payload.
        data.Add("oauth_signature", GenerateSignature(fullUrl, data));

        // Build the OAuth HTTP Header from the data.
        string oAuthHeader = GenerateOAuthHeader(data);

        // Build the form data (exclude OAuth stuff that's already in the header).
        var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data.Where(kvp => !kvp.Key.StartsWith("oauth_")));

        return SendRequest(fullUrl, oAuthHeader, formData);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate an OAuth signature from OAuth header values.
    /// </summary>
    string GenerateSignature(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var sigString = string.Join(
            "&",
            data
                .Union(data)
                .Select(kvp => string.Format("{0}={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key), Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value)))
                .OrderBy(s => s)
        );

        var fullSigData = string.Format(
            "{0}&{1}&{2}",
            "POST",
            Uri.EscapeDataString(url),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(sigString.ToString())
        );

        return Convert.ToBase64String(sigHasher.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(fullSigData.ToString())));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate the raw OAuth HTML header from the values (including signature).
    /// </summary>
    string GenerateOAuthHeader(Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        return "OAuth " + string.Join(
            ", ",
            data
                .Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith("oauth_"))
                .Select(kvp => string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key), Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value)))
                .OrderBy(s => s)
        );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send HTTP Request and return the response.
    /// </summary>
    async Task<string> SendRequest(string fullUrl, string oAuthHeader, FormUrlEncodedContent formData)
    {
        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);

            var httpResp = await http.PostAsync(fullUrl, formData);
            var respBody = await httpResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return respBody;
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
var twitter = new TwitterApi(ConsumerKey, ConsumerKeySecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
var response = await twitter.Tweet("This is my first automated tweet!");
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Works with .NET Core too (i.e. no references to System.Web, etc.).

A similar but more in depth example (e.g. upload images) exists here:

[C# / .NET Core, publish to Twitter](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2017/11/24/csharp-dotnet-core-publish-twitter/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading up on the documentation on http://developer.twitter.com/start. It has all the information you will need.

Comment: url no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has its own [API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) to do that

Comment: The link is broken.