# Integrating Twitter in the .net web application

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

I got a Website where the registered user can set the set the social net settings.say they can keep connected to the Facebook and Twitter.once this is set whenever the user post a media or comment the tweet or posts will be send to Facebook and Twitter respectively.
I implemented the Signin with TWitter with OAuth.My pain points are these
1)Need to stop redirecting the application to Twittwer on click of sign in.
   For this I can open it in a pop up.still post auth the popup window itself gets redirected to the call back url,so I have 2 windows with same content.
2)need to know how to post tweets whenever user share a media or comments in my site

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: You might find your answer here: [Post “Hello World” to twitter from .NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849455/post-hello-world-to-twitter-from-net-application)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/), it has examples of how to post tweets etc ...

Once you have familiarised yourself with TweetSharp, if you have some more specific questions, then post them here.

Comment: Th link to Tweetsharp is dead.